# The geositemap file(s) is/are blocking your XML sitemaps from working properly in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to wordpress when i uploaded the geositemap through filemanager I get this issue in wordpress **SEO Yoast plugin** on top like this

The following file(s) is/are blocking your XML sitemaps from working properly:

```
/home/wallerrealestate/public_html/geositemap.xml
```

Either delete them (this can be done with the "**Fix it**" button) or disable `Yoast SEO XML sitemaps`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this yoast plugin is very easy. If you want to use Yoast’s sitemap function, than delete the physical file located at the path in the error message. You can automatically delete the file by clicking the “Fix it” button or manually through FTP or a file manager. If you are unsure how to delete files on your server, please contact your webhost.
if You want to know more you can visit here i have explained it with pictures
http://techynews4u.com/yoast-error-file-is-blocking-your-xml-sitemaps-from-working-properly/